# Google analytics set custom dimension value

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Below, I've set my `dimension1` value to `dimensionValue`.
This is a variable that I created above this snippet of code. 
The code above is a function that generates random number and letter and stores inside the variable `dimensionValue`, `var dimensionValue = (formula for random string...)`

In my google analytics, the custom dimension was outputting `dimensionValue` for each user when I filtered for `dimension1` in GA, whereas it should be outputting EE12345 etc.

On this line of code `ga('set', 'dimension1', 'dimensionValue');` is dimensionValue written correctly with backticks around it, or should it contain no backticks

```
function getRChar() {
    return (Math.random() * 26 + 10 | 0).toString(36).toUpperCase();
    }

    var dimensionValue = getRChar() + getRChar() + Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999) * 7);

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'dimensionValue');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: Drop the quotes. As it stands dimensionValue is interpreted as a fixed string, not as a variable, so you always get the value of the string (which is of course always the same).

Comment: This explains everything, thank you @EikePierstorff

Comment: @EikePierstorff how should I set my domain name up when creating my pageview `ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-Y', 'auto');` Where it says auto, should that be www.domain.com or http:// www.domain.com or domain.com?

Comment: This should really be a separate question, but "auto" sets the cookie domain to the highest possible level (so the cookie is valid for domain.com and all subdomains like www.domain.com, test.domain.com etc.). One of the very few use cases where you would not use "auto" is if you want to track a subdomain but not the "main" domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Eike explained in the comments:

> Drop the quotes. As it stands dimensionValue is interpreted as a fixed
>   string, not as a variable, so you always get the value of the string
>   (which is of course always the same).

Solution:

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', dimensionValue);
```